# spring boot app not connecting to activemq which is running in a docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, jms, activemq-classic

I have an ActiveMQ instance running on Docker in my local machine, and I also have a Spring Boot app running in another Docker instance. I am not able to connect to the queue from the app. Please let me know what broker URL I should give. I tried the name of Docker container and the IP of container in the following format:

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://172.17.0.2:61616
```

I ran ActiveMQ using following command:

```
docker run -p 61616:61616 -d  webcenter/activemq
```

I am getting socket timeout.

Comment: Did you check if port is open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the two container in the same docker network and then you can use the container name to connect to MQ.